# React Native Animated Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: react-native, user-interface, mobile, horizontal-scrolling

I am beginner in React native and I want to implement the horizontal scrolling list like this.
[Design](https://dribbble.com/shots/8208030-Mobile-app-Motion-animation-Adobe-Xd). Can anyone let me know about the references/libraries that I can use to design this in React Native Expo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [snap carousal](https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel), or `FlatList` with snapping enabled